# How to fix KeyValuePair<char, int[]> in foreach statement?

Tags: c#

How can I use KeyValuePair in `foreach` statement?

The error is

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<char, int[]> characterEntry in occ_counts_before.Keys)
{
   characterEntry.Value[i] = characterEntry.Value[i - 1] + (characterEntry.Key == current ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.Keys`

Comment: what is `current`?

Comment: where is `i` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the `Keys` and thus receive in the iterator a `char` not a `KeyValuePair`.
Simply remove the property `Key` from your `foreach`.

You would see this if you used `var` instead. When you attempt to access characterEntry it will clearly show it is a `char` and not a `KeyValuePair`. When you remove `Keys` from the iteration you will then see it is a `KeyValuePair` allowing you to access the `char` from `.Key` and the `int[]` from `.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `occ_counts_before` implements `IDictionary`, `Keys` is just a collection of `char`, not `KeyValuePair`. Also, the body of your `foreach` is trying to change `Value`, which is read-only. To fix it, you'll need iterate over your dictionary's keys, and use each key to access the corresponding value:

```
foreach(char key in occ_counts_before.Keys)
{
  occ_counts_before[key][i] = occ_counts_before[key][i - 1] + (key == current ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you even tried this? It's semmantically correct but would not accomplish what the OP wants.

Comment: Fair point. The body of the foreach uses both `Key` and `Value`, so they probably want to use either the first or second option. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, they're assigning the Value. My bad.

Answer (score -2):

To change the value for the entry you need to retrieve it by key.

```
foreach (char entryKey in occ_counts_before.Keys) {
    occ_counts_before[entryKey] = new int[] { }; // I can't figure out what are you assinging here so i put a empty int array, but you can figure out this yourself
}
```

Note the change in the **foreach**

Comment: The user is also using the Value part of the KeyValuePair.  Your post ignores that.

Comment: To assign the value you need to occ_counts_before[entryKey], The Value property occ_counts_before[entryKey].Value it's read-only